# Python: Split text by keyword into excel rows

Tags: python, regex, text, extract, sentiment-analysis

New to programming, found a lot of helpful threads already, but just not quite what I need.
I have one text file that looks like:

```
  1 of 5000 DOCUMENTS


                    Copyright 2010 The Deal, L.L.C.
                          All Rights Reserved
                          Daily Deal/The Deal

                        January 12, 2010 Tuesday

HEADLINE: Cadbury slams Kraft bid

BODY:

  On cue .....

......

body of article here

......

DEAL SIZE

$ 10-50 Billion

                            2 of 5000 DOCUMENTS


                    Copyright 2015 The Deal, L.L.C.
                          All Rights Reserved
                           The Deal Pipeline

                      September 17, 2015 Thursday

HEADLINE: Perrigo rejects formal offer from Mylan

BODY: 
(and here again the body of this article)

DEAL SIZE
```

As output I would like JUST the body of every article in a new row (one cell per article body) in one file (I have around 5000 articles to process like this). The output would be 5000 rows and 1 column.
From what I could find it seems 're' would be the best solution. So the recurring keywords are BODY: and perhaps DOCUMENTS. How do I extract just the text between those keywords into a new row in excel for every article?

```
import re
inputtext = 'F:\text.txt'
re.split(r'\n(?=BODY:)', inputtext)
```

or something like this?

```
section = []
for line in open_file_object:
if line.startswith('BODY:'):
    # new section
    if section:
        process_section(section)
    section = [line]
else:
    section.append(line)
if section:
process_section(section)
```

I'm a bit lost in where to look, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to ewwink I'm currently here:

```
import re
articlesBody = None
with open('F:\CloudStation\Bocconi University\MSc. Thesis\\test folder\majortest.txt', 'r') as txt:
  inputtext = txt.read()
  articlesBody = re.findall(r'BODY:(.+?)\d\sDOCUMENTS', inputtext, re.S)

#print(articlesBody)
#print(type(articlesBody))

  with open('result.csv', 'w') as csv:
   for item in articlesBody:
    item = item.replace('\n', ' ')
    csv.write('"%s",' % item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working with file use `with open('F:\text.txt', mode)` where `mode` are `'r'` for reading and `'w'` for writing, to extract the content use `re.findall` and finally you need to escape new line `\n`, double quotes `"`and maybe other character.

```
import re

articlesBody = None
with open('text.txt', 'r') as txt:
  inputtext = txt.read()
  articlesBody = re.findall(r'BODY:(.+?)\d\sof\s5000', inputtext, re.S)

#print(articlesBody)

with open('result.csv', 'w') as csv:
  for item in articlesBody:
    item = item.replace('\n', '\\n').replace('"', '""')
    csv.write('"%s",' % item)
```

another note: try with small content

Comment: Thanks, I will try!
   
    (r'BODY:(.+?)\d\sof\s5000

what does the part after BODY: do?

Comment: regex to capture text between `BODY:` and `2 of 5000 DOCUMENTS`

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation, i'll change it to d\sDOCUMENTS. To be clear, I'm running it on 7 documents now, so there are 7 news articles. each of them has a 'BODY:' at the start of text and at the end of each article it says 'x of 7 DOCUMENTS'.
I'd like every body of text to appear in a separate cell in the result.csv, so I will have a result.csv with 1 column and 7 rows in this case.
Right now, it extracts the bodies of text, however it puts them in the same cell, right after eachother. Also the \n appear in the excel file

Comment: to remove `\n` do `.replace('\n', '')` . if all in same cell it should  be your csv program not use comma `,` as separator. you can change comma separator here `'"%s",'`

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the separation. But now it only writes the first article in the first cell, how do I loop/repeat it, so it keeps going until it can't find any more BODY: down the document?

Comment: `re.findall` will return all matches text, if only return first article you need to repair your regex

Comment: I edited the question. The regex seems fine, i changed it to: `` `re.findall(r'BODY:(.+?)\d\sof\s7', inputtext, re.S)`  
however, it still only writes the first body of text to the first cell. second body of text isn't written anywhere and the 2nd cell is empty.